# Why does the help suggest to end the lhs of a plug mapping with a semicolon?

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-system, help-system

In [`:help using-<Plug>`](https://vimhelp.org/usr_51.txt.html#using-%3CPlug%3E) a suggestion is given as to how to name the left hand side of a `<Plug>` mapping:

> To make it very unlikely that other plugins use the same sequence of characters, use this structure: <Plug> scriptname mapname
> In our example the scriptname is "Typecorr" and the mapname is "Add". We add a semicolon as the terminator.  This results in "TypecorrAdd;".

but I don't understand what the purpose of the `;` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the given example correctly, the purpose of that semicolon is to visually separate the `<Plug>` mapping from any subsequent command, as in the imaginary:

```
nmap xx <Plug>FooBarx    " Is it 'rx' at the end?
nmap xx <Plug>FooBar;x   " Oh… OK I guess
```

But I don't think that's a particularly good pattern, mostly because `;` is a legitimate command, which can lead to more confusion. And it is only provided as an example anyway, not as a guideline. The name doesn't have to be in PascalCase and it doesn't have to end with a semicolon either.

AFAIK, the most common real world pattern is actually to wrap the name in parentheses:

```
<Plug>(FooBar)
<Plug>(foo_bar)
" etc.
```

which makes boundaries very clear and non-ambiguous, in a "it starts here and it ends there" kind of way:

```
nmap xx <Plug>(FooBar)x
```

Note that the parentheses are not some obscure vimscript expression thing, they are literally part of the name so you can be creative:

```
<Plug><FooBar>
<Plug>[fooBar]
<Plug>{foo_bar}
<Plug>§1337§
" etc.
```

at the risk of puzzling both your users and your fellow community members trying to help.

You should stick with the parentheses.